# How to create a different user category in SharePoint and a view designated only for them?

Tags: sharepoint, listview, user-controls

1. How do I create a different users category? (more restrictive - with view only properties)?

   2. How do I create a View - only for this category of users?

I need to group some users into a view only category and then assign only ONE view to this group, so they can not see everything that is in my list.
SharePoint, so far, does not give the option to restrict access at cell level so I need to go around this and create a view for this group, with the condition that all that they can see is this View (and they should not be able to add columns to this view).

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are not using MOSS? If so, take a look a audience targetting.

Comment: I use SharePoint 2007. So far I have three users categories set up (Admin, Members and Visitors - SharePoint standard), but I need a 4th category - more restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want to restrict the List View to only specific set of users. You have the following options

1. [Doing it in the SharePoint UI](http://vspug.com/sam/2007/10/16/how-to-restrict-public-access-to-sharepoint-list-views-using-filters/) but not suitable if you have lots of item and you want to do it for a SharePoint Group.
2. [Open Source - CodePlex](http://prequest01.wordpress.com/2008/12/18/restrict-views-for-user-groups-for-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint/) Good one I have tried it - It has got what exactly you want Column level restriction
3. [Third Party](http://www.datapolis.com/en/Offer/Products/Pages/SCP.aspx) in case if you feel to spend $ - Seriously I didn't try this tool.
4. [Another Option to do it in SharePoint UI](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/06/restricting-access-to-sharepoint-views.html) - Quick solution but - Wont prevent user from creating their Own Views.

Comment: Thanks Janis, now I fixed the Link